# Photo app like scrolling in scroll view in zoom mode with gesture recognizers 

Tags: iphone, ipad, uiscrollview, scroll, uigesturerecognizer

I have come to SO with a question after a long time, I haven't learned enough yet :(.

I am having a `UIScrollView` which has `UIImageView` inside it. The image of the `UIImageView` is to change with a right and left swipe. I know overriding the touches of `UIScrollView` will not be a good and efficient solution, so I added a transparent view upon the `UIScrollView` (not as its subview) covering the bounds of `UIScrollView` and overridden its touch methods to change the images on swipe.

Now with the help of pinch `gesture recognizer` added to my transparent view I am able to zoom the `UIScrollView` and the image programmatically. Till here, I am able to work the things smoothly but I have another typical functionality. I have to move the zoomed image with my finger up and down so that I can see the cropped image. I am doing it with the help of `UILongPressGestureRecognizer` added to my transparent view. Upon 1 seconds of touch duration I add a `UIImageView` with a four way arrow image and add it touch location. Now as I move my finger, the `fourwayarrow image` follows my finger but the image in the scrollview does not follow my finger. Its kind of jerky and often works like I have tied an elastic string. So initially I have to pull the string to some threshold (till that point the scroll view does not move) and when it reaches that level, it suddenly starts moving out of control. I am adding the code here for you people to have a look.

Please feel free to add comments if you people need any other information.

```
- (void) handleLongPress:(UILongPressGestureRecognizer *)longPressGestureRecognizer{
    CGPoint touchLocation = [longPressGestureRecognizer locationInView:self.transparentLayer];
    switch (longPressGestureRecognizer.state) {
        case UIGestureRecognizerStatePossible: break;
        case UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan:{
            if (fourWayArrowImageView == nil) {
                fourWayArrowImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"4wayarrow.png"]];
                [fourWayArrowImageView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
            }
            _previousLocation.x = touchLocation.x;
            _previousLocation.y = touchLocation.y;
            [fourWayArrowImageView setCenter:touchLocation];
            [self.transparentLayer addSubview:fourWayArrowImageView];
        }
            break;
        case UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged:{
            float dx = (touchLocation.x - _previousLocation.x);
            float dy = (touchLocation.y - _previousLocation.y);
            CGPoint currentMaxOffset = [self currentMaxOffset];
            CGPoint currentOffset = [self.rotatableImageViewContainingScrollView contentOffset];
            float theScale = [self.rotatableImageViewContainingScrollView zoomScale];
            currentOffset.x -= (dx*theScale);
            currentOffset.y -= (dy*theScale);

            [fourWayArrowImageView setCenter:touchLocation];
            CGSize size = self.rotatableImageViewContainingScrollView.frame.size;
            [self.rotatableImageViewContainingScrollView scrollRectToVisible:CGRectMake(currentOffset.x, currentOffset.y, size.width, size.height) animated:YES];
            _prevMaxOffset = CGPointMake(currentMaxOffset.x, currentMaxOffset.y);
        }
            break;
        case UIGestureRecognizerStateCancelled:
        case UIGestureRecognizerStateFailed:
        case UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded: [fourWayArrowImageView removeFromSuperview]; break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution. Actually I was doing a mistake. I was not updating the previous location after the scrolling and the scrolling should not be animated in this case. So please look at the answer. BTW thanks to all guys who gave time:

```
- (void) handleLongPress:(UILongPressGestureRecognizer *)longPressGestureRecognizer{
    CGPoint touchLocation = [longPressGestureRecognizer locationInView:self.transparentLayer];
    switch (longPressGestureRecognizer.state) {
        case UIGestureRecognizerStatePossible: break;
        case UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan:{
            if (fourWayArrowImageView == nil) {
                fourWayArrowImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"4wayarrow.png"]];
                [fourWayArrowImageView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
            }
            _previousLocation = CGPointMake(touchLocation.x, touchLocation.y);
            [fourWayArrowImageView setCenter:touchLocation];
            [self.transparentLayer addSubview:fourWayArrowImageView];
        }
            break;
        case UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged:{
            float dx = (touchLocation.x - _previousLocation.x);
            float dy = (touchLocation.y - _previousLocation.y);
            CGPoint currentMaxOffset = [self currentMaxOffset];
            CGPoint currentOffset = [self.rotatableImageViewContainingScrollView contentOffset];
            //float theScale = [self.rotatableImageViewContainingScrollView zoomScale];
            //currentOffset.x -= (dx*theScale);
            //currentOffset.y -= (dy*theScale);
            currentOffset.x -= (dx);
            currentOffset.y -= (dy);
            [fourWayArrowImageView setCenter:touchLocation];
            CGSize size = self.rotatableImageViewContainingScrollView.frame.size;
            [self.rotatableImageViewContainingScrollView scrollRectToVisible:CGRectMake(currentOffset.x, currentOffset.y, size.width, size.height) animated:NO]; //bool value in animated should be false.
            _prevMaxOffset = CGPointMake(currentMaxOffset.x, currentMaxOffset.y);
            _previousLocation = CGPointMake(touchLocation.x, touchLocation.y); // added this line in the answer.
        }
            break;
        case UIGestureRecognizerStateCancelled:
        case UIGestureRecognizerStateFailed:
        case UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded: [fourWayArrowImageView removeFromSuperview]; break;
    }
}
```

So the scrolling in zoom mode now exactly works like photo app.

Hope this helps

Comment: You are doing this in a really roundabout way. You should take a look at Apple's PhotoScroller sample code. You can use a paging scrollview and use the standard zooming/panning support built in to UIScrollView. You don't need to do all this work yourself.

Comment: @MikeWeller Thanks Mike.. But I have a client requirement to do the rotations with swipe at any zoom level.. that can not be done with scroll view's default zooming and scrolling as you can not swipe when its is zoomed mode. So I had to do things in this way